# Problem with small bash script

Tags: find, grep, bash-script

I often run `find` in my code projects when I make a change somewhere and I have to find where it impacts other pieces of code, so I thought about writing a very small script to make this easier, call it `blah.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash -eu

if [ $# -ne 3 ]; then
    echo "Three inputs required"
else
    find $1 -name $2 -exec grep -iHn $3 {} \;
fi
```

The problem is, I get an error when the third argument (the text I'm looking for) contains a space. For example, `blah . '*.php' 'foo bar'` returns `grep: bar: No such file or directory` for each file `grep` tried to explore. I'm sure it's a silly mistake, I'm not really hands on with bash..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

have you tried like this:

```
find "$1" -name "$2" -exec grep -iHne "$3" {} +
```

Without the quotes, bash performs word splitting and filename generation on the variables, so they wind up getting passed as multiple arguments.

Comment: You forgot a couple.

Comment: Hmm, I was sure I tried that and got another error when I passed a third argument with double quotes, but it's working right now with the query I had in mind..

Comment: I added in quoting the other two parameters and also a brief explanation of why. Please feel free to revert if you don't agree.

Comment: Alright, well, it seems to work now, I must have done something wrong when I tried before... Thanks, that was easy :)